# Why can't I minimize the squared distance?

Tags: geometry, optimization

My question is "Why can't I minimize the squared distance?" It would be a lot easier, but it yields the wrong answer.

I set out to write an example for using Newton's Method for Multiple equations and decided to show the following problem. Given a line, such as $\space 4x+3y-7=0 \space$ and three points, $A=(1,4), \space B=(3,4), \space C=(-1,-1)$, find the point on the line that is the shortest summed distance to all three points. A nearly identical problem has been discussed in this forum here. [How to find the point on a line which has the minimum length to three points?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2849394/how-to-find-the-point-on-a-line-which-has-the-minimum-length-to-three-points)
I used Lagrange optimization to set up my problem and solved it with Geogebra's CAS, before writing code in SAGEmath. The Lagrange system is as follows.
$$\mathscr{L}(x,y,\lambda)=\Vert{A-(x,y)}\Vert+\Vert B-(x,y)\Vert+\Vert C-(x,y)\Vert -\lambda \left(4x+3y-7\right) \tag{EQ 1} \label{EQ_1}$$

I took the partial derivatives, set them to zero and solved the system. However, it was a lot easier to manipulate the derivatives if I squared the equations first. That is, I wanted my Lagrange system to be
$$\mathscr{L}(x,y,\lambda)=\left[(1-x)^2+(4-y)^2\right]+\left[(3-x)^2+(4-y)^2\right]+\left[(-1-x)^2+(-1-y)^2\right] -\lambda \left(4x+3y-7\right) \tag{EQ 2} \label{EQ 2}$$ When I am only using one point, this works perfectly and I rationalize it by saying, ". . .this has to be a non-negative function since it is difficult to imagine a negative distance. Any non-negative function will have the same minimum as its square since at every point it would be multiplied by itself." If I use $\eqref{EQ 2}$ it indeed minimizes the squared distance from the 3 points to the line, but that distance is not the same as the minimum distance to the line.  I have a working example at https://www.geogebra.org/m/hptbypvy .  It takes 20 or 30 sec to load and I have to tell my browser to wait a couple of times.

Comment: In general , $a_1^2 + \ldots + a_m^2$ (where $a_1, \ldots, a_m$ are distances in your case) is not a function of $a_1 + \ldots + a_m$, so minimizing one is not equivalent to minimizing the other.

Comment: In effect you seem to be asking why the point which minimises the sum of squares of distances is (a) not the same point which minimises the sum of absolute distances and (b) is easier to find.  (This is related to the difference in statistics between the mean and the median.)  The answer to (a) is essentially a different rule will produce different results, while the answer to (b) is essentially that the derivatives of $x^2+y^2$ are much simpler than the derivatives of $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ as you have observed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably thinking of the following fact: minimizing $\sqrt{d^2}$ is equivalent to minimizing $d^2$ because $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is a monotonic increasing function.

But once you introduce sums you throw things off. Minimizing $\sum\sqrt{d_i^2}=\sum|d_i|$ is not equivalent to minimizing $\sum d_i^2$.

Look at a simple example. Take $d_i=(i-x)$, for $i=1, 2, 6$.

The minimum of $\sum d_i^2=(1-x)^2+(2-x)^2+(6-x)^2=3x^2-18x+41$ occurs at $x=3$.

But the minimum of $\sum\sqrt{d_i^2}=|1-x|+|2-x|+|6-x|$ occurs at $x=2$.

This is related to the fact that the *mean* minimizes the sum of **squared** deviations, while the *median* minimizes the sum of **absolute** deviations.

Answer (score 0):

It was not clear to me what your actual question was.

If you asked why minimizing square distance to 3 points produces a different result that minimizing total distance (in terms of absolute value), this can be explained quite intuitively. When you use a linear distance function, the optimizer will prefer distances $1,0,4$ to $1,2,3$ since the sum distances are $5$ and $6$, respectively. However, the square optimizer will clearly prefer the other way, since $1^2+2^2+3^3=14$ and $1^2+0^2+4^2=17$...

Answer (score 0):

Why should you should get the same answer in both cases? Here is a simpler example. At which points does the function $x\mapsto|x-1|+|x+1|$ attain its minimum? Answer: at every point of the interval $[-1,1]$. And at which points does the function $x\mapsto|x-1|^2+|x+1|^2$ attain its minimum? Answer: at $0$ and *only* at $0$.